# How to find a right screw for a hole

Tags: screws, drill, hole, anchor, measurement

I want to hang some stuff on my wall so here it comes to the part where I need to get screws/anchors.

Saying I have a hole in a piece that I would like to attach(a picture attached), how can I measure it and get the right stuff?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a picture of that hole with a ruler across it, so we can see what size it is? Or, tell us the diameter. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What is the weight?  And a picture of the entire object will help. A light object can still require a strong anchor if it is cantilevered.